# How to pass Request Object from a form to Php

Tags: php, laravel, forms, request

I am developing a Laravel application using Laravel 5.7 and I have following problem:

1. I am passing a request object "req" from controller to view.
2. In view I show the contents of request object passed to view
3. I have a form in the same view which is suppose to forward the same request object "req" to a controller where I do some processing with it but can't figure out how can I send the whole request object rather than sending individual elements.

I want to do something like this

```
<form method="post" action="/story/editorsubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <input type="hidden" name="fullobject" value={{ $req }}>

    <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to loop through the object properties and create hidden input fields with it with a foreach?

Comment: Looking at your problem, the `$request->flash();` is just all what you might be looking for! If you need to print it back, use `$request->old('username');` or in your form `<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">`. See the documentation about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests

Comment: where should I put `$request->flash()`? any code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data submitted from the form is what becomes the request.  Also you were missing some quotes.

```
<form method="post" action="/story/editorsubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <input type="hidden" name="fullobject" value="{{ $req }}">

    <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Your current data could be accessed in the controller on form submit using the name of the submitted property.  But I doubt this would work as $req is an object, not a string.

```
$object = request('fullobject');
```

But ideally, you should be defining the properties separately.  I'm assuming these hidden elements actually represent editable form inputs?  If nothing is changing, it doesn't make sense to do it this way.

EDIT: Added way of dealing with arrays.

```
<form method="post" action="/story/editorsubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    @foreach ($req->all() as $key => $value)
        @if (is_array($value))
            @foreach($value as $v)
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ $key }}[]" value="{{ $v }}">
            @endforeach
        @else
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ $key }}" value='{{ $value }}'>
        @endif
    @endforeach

    <button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Then the submitted request would contain the individual properties like before.

Comment: Yep, this is what I suggested but wasn't sure if this was the best approach.

Comment: Just a minor correction, {{ key }} should be {{ $key }}. I got array to string conversion error on @endforeach line. There are some fields that has base64 images files in them. could that be the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  I don't think it would.  It's more likely that your `$req` object contains one or more values that are arrays.  Would you be willing to elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do?  Maybe post a dump of your request `dd($req->all())` so we can see the data types?

Comment: `+request: ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:11 [▼
      "_token" => "VjhQlax2U9QdWWtiY2E6rkUY1tlmdbEbcXBI4Cye"
      "title" => null
      "titleimageTemp" => "<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ... ▶"
      "category" => "novalue"
      "description" => null
      "storytextTemp" => null
      "storytext" => null
      "includename" => array:1 [▼
        0 => null
      ]
      "storyprice" => null
      "safeforkids" => "yes"
      "submitButton" => "Preview"
    ]
  }`

Comment: It shows that `includename` is an array, as I expected.  Base64 is typically safe, but you didn't mention they were full image tags.  In this case, we need to account for the double quotes.  Easiest thing to do is switch the value field to single quotes.  I can post some edits that should allow this to work in a moment.

Comment: @matticustard your solution solved my problem so I am going to accept it as answer. After you asked for a dump I realized that there was an array in the request which was causing the problem. For now i have removed that array from my form but is there a way to deal with arrays in the request using your above solution?

Comment: Just added a fix for that.

Comment: Added one more edit, forgot to add the single quotes we talked about for the image tags.

Comment: Good luck with everything!